# Debugging ML proofs in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle, ml

I wrote the following ML code:

```
lemma fstI: "x = (y, z) ⟹ y = fst x"
  by simp

ML ‹
val ctxt0 = @{context};
val ctxt = ctxt0;
val (_,ctxt) = Variable.add_fixes ["z1'","x1'","y1'","x1", "y1", "x2", "y2"] ctxt;
val (assms,ctxt) = Assumption.add_assumes 
                       [@{cprop "z1' = (x1',y1')"},@{cprop "z1' = ext_add (x1,y1) (x2,y2)"}] ctxt;
val th1 = @{thm fstI}  OF  [(nth assms 0)]
val th2 = Thm.instantiate' [SOME @{ctyp "'a"}] [SOME @{cterm "fst::'a×'a ⇒ 'a"}] (@{thm arg_cong} OF [(nth assms 1)])
val x1'_expr = Goal.prove ctxt [] []
                               @{prop "x1' = fst (ext_add (x1,y1) (x2,y2))"}
                          (fn _ => EqSubst.eqsubst_tac ctxt [1] [th1] 1
                                  THEN EqSubst.eqsubst_tac ctxt [1] [th2] 1
                                  THEN simp_tac ctxt 1)
›
```

corresponding to the following Isar proof:

```
lemma taylored_assoc: 
  assumes "z1' = (x1',y1')"
          "z1' = ext_add (x1,y1) (x2,y2)" "z3' = add (x2,y2) (x3,y3)" 
  shows "x1' = fst (ext_add (x1,y1) (x2,y2))"   
  by(tactic ‹EqSubst.eqsubst_tac @{context} [1] [@{thm fstI[OF assms(1)]}] 1
                THEN EqSubst.eqsubst_tac @{context} [1] [@{thm arg_cong[OF assms(2), of fst]}] 1
                THEN simp_tac @{context} 1›)
```

The ML version of it is not working for some reason? How could I debug this? There is the print_tac tactic, but it only acccepts strings, while I would like to print the actual subgoal after each tactic is applied.

Comment: "There is the `print_tac` tactic, but it only accepts strings." Why is this a problem? `print_tac` worked quite well for me in the past. From time to time, I also used `Subgoal.FOCUS` for the purpose of debugging tactics.

Comment: @xanonec, I want to print the goal after the first substitution so that I see why at the ML level is failing... I have the feeling that something might be wrong with the context but I have no means to check that

Comment: It does not seem like this is something that `print_tac` cannot do. Why can you not insert `THEN print_tac @{context} ""` in the appropriate location? If this is not an option, then you should be able to print any relevant information once you are 'inside' `SUBPROOF` or `Subgoal.FOCUS`: see the implementation manual or the Isabelle/ML cookbook for more information and examples.

Comment: @xanonec that didnt work for me...i'm trying the debugging tool for ml (in case it makes no sense to do so)

Comment: @xanonec on top of the above, I have the feeling that the problem may be the context: Isabelle’s generic Simplifier [14] is already a non-trivial example of integrating
automated proof tools into our architecture of context data and declarations
(cf. §3). The generic proof method simp depends on a simpset container being
maintained as context data. (from http://www21.in.tum.de/~wenzelm/papers/context-methods.pdf), so basically I think the simplifier might be getting the context from the theory and not from the actual proof...just as an idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the problem is related to the type inference: in the antiquotation `@{cprop "z1' = (x1',y1')"}` there is no simple way to infer the desired type `'a` of the variables `x1'` and `y1'` automatically because each antiquotation in the list of assumptions is pre-processed independently of other antiquotations before being passed to `add_assumes`. Therefore, the most general type is inferred. You merely need to provide the type of each variable explicitly, e.g. `@{cprop "z1' = (x1'::'a,y1'::'a)"}` and the tactic should work. However, in my view, a better solution would be to define the variables such as `x1'` and `y1'` directly in ML with the explicit type assignment, e.g. `val x1t = Free("x1", T)`, where T is the desired type `'a`.